# Change data in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have got problem with changing data in one of the column from my pandas Dataframe (about 51000x11 size).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_answers.head(10)
```

[image]

```
set(df_answers['Gender'])
```

There are 29 types of answers in 'Gender' columns

```
{'Female',
 'Female; Gender non-conforming',
 'Female; Gender non-conforming; Other',
 'Female; Other',
 'Female; Transgender',
 'Female; Transgender; Gender non-conforming',
 'Female; Transgender; Gender non-conforming; Other',
 'Female; Transgender; Other',
 'Gender non-conforming',
 'Gender non-conforming; Other',
 'Male',
 'Male; Female',
 'Male; Female; Gender non-conforming',
 'Male; Female; Gender non-conforming; Other',
 'Male; Female; Other',
 'Male; Female; Transgender',
 'Male; Female; Transgender; Gender non-conforming',
 'Male; Female; Transgender; Gender non-conforming; Other',
 'Male; Female; Transgender; Other',
 'Male; Gender non-conforming',
 'Male; Gender non-conforming; Other',
 'Male; Other',
 'Male; Transgender',
 'Male; Transgender; Gender non-conforming',
 'Male; Transgender; Other',
 'Other',
 'Transgender',
 'Transgender; Gender non-conforming',
 'Transgender; Other',
 nan}
```

I want to change this mess - left 2 options 'Female', 'Male' as they are and change(replace) everything else into 'Other'.
My function wrote below unfortunately does not work - I suspect that probably something is wrong with .isin() or .loc[], but I am not sure.

```
def change_gender_name():
    if (df_answers.loc[~df_answers['Gender'].isin(['Female', 'Male'])]):
        df_answers['Gender'] = df_answers['Gender'].str.replace('*', 'Other', regex=True, inplace=True)
    else:
        pass

change_gender_name()
```

*ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().*

Thanks for your time.

I put some extra info, because as I thought it is not easy task.

When data in column is equal 'Female', 'Male' or 'Other' (without any additionl words inside), I want to left them as they are; all 26 different types of data I want to change into 'Other' string.

> 'Female', 'Male', 'Other' - they are the final answers inside this
> column

Comment: `df['new_gender'] = np.where((df['Gender'] != 'Male') | (df['Gender'] != 'Female'), 'Other', df['Gender'])`

Comment: put this inside function or as independent part of code (without function)?

Comment: You do not need a function. Just run it as its own line.

Comment: `df['New_Gender'] = df['Gender'].str.replace('^(?!.*Female)(?!.*Male).*', 'Other')`?

Comment: @It_is_Chris It doesn't work - now there are only one unique data in column: 'Other'.

Comment: @KrzysztofSobota you are correct, I made a mistake in the logic: `df['new_gender'] = np.where(df['Gender'].isin(['Male', 'Female']), df['Gender'], 'Other')`

Comment: to Wiktor: it also doesn't work, because after repeat set() method I get 29 options as before

Comment: to Chris: Yes, now it works. Thanks for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest syntax:

```
 df[df['filtered_column']=='filter'] = 'inserted_value'
```

In your case its something like:

```
s = df_answers['Gender']
s[~s['Gender'].isin(['Female','Male'])] = 'Other'
df_answers['Gender'] = s
```

Below syntax proposed by @PaulH in comments, which is actually a better solution. More readable:

```
df.loc[~df['Gender'].isin(['Female','Male']), 'Gender'] = 'Other'
```

Comment: don't chain your indexers when assigning values

Comment: <ipython-input-5-ca93773cd0bd>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Comment: @PaulH good point, it leads to 'SettingWithCopyWarning'. It can be done on series separated before then. I'm modifying answer.

Comment: I would use the `.loc` accessor: `df.loc[~df['Gender'].isin(['Female','Male']), 'Gender'] = 'Other'`

Comment: Does it improve performance, except for providing better readability?

Answer (score 0):

Here an alternative:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

m = {'Female',
 'Female; Gender non-conforming',
 'Female; Gender non-conforming; Other',
 'Female; Other',
 'Female; Transgender',
 'Female; Transgender; Gender non-conforming',
 'Female; Transgender; Gender non-conforming; Other',
 'Female; Transgender; Other',
 'Gender non-conforming',
 'Gender non-conforming; Other',
 'Male',
 'Male; Female',
 'Male; Female; Gender non-conforming',
 'Male; Female; Gender non-conforming; Other',
 'Male; Female; Other',
 'Male; Female; Transgender',
 'Male; Female; Transgender; Gender non-conforming',
 'Male; Female; Transgender; Gender non-conforming; Other',
 'Male; Female; Transgender; Other',
 'Male; Gender non-conforming',
 'Male; Gender non-conforming; Other',
 'Male; Other',
 'Male; Transgender',
 'Male; Transgender; Gender non-conforming',
 'Male; Transgender; Other',
 'Other',
 'Transgender',
 'Transgender; Gender non-conforming',
 'Transgender; Other',
 np.nan}

df_answers = pd.DataFrame(m)
df_answers.columns=['Gender']
```

That was to reproduce the question.
Here a couple of functions
This function helps to select the correct answers and left aside the others:

```
def change_words(y):
    if y.__contains__('Male') | y.__contains__('Female'):
        return y
    else:
        return 'Other'
```

Feel  free to use this one instead:

```
def change_words_v2(y):
    if y in ['Male','Female']:
        return y
    else:
        return 'Other'
```

This function is to cover every particular case

```
def simplify_gender(x):
    new_x = []
    for y in str(x).split('; '):
        new_x.append(change_words(y))
    return '; '.join(new_x)
```

All together in this way:

```
df_answers.applymap(lambda x: simplify_gender(x))
                               Gender
0                               Other
1          Male; Female; Other; Other
2          Male; Female; Other; Other
3                 Male; Female; Other
4         Female; Other; Other; Other
5                         Male; Other
6                         Male; Other
7                       Female; Other
8                        Other; Other
9                        Other; Other
10                Male; Female; Other
11                 Male; Other; Other
12                       Other; Other
13               Female; Other; Other
14                       Male; Female
15                              Other
16         Male; Female; Other; Other
17                              Other
18                        Male; Other
19                      Female; Other
20                 Male; Other; Other
21                 Male; Other; Other
22                              Other
23                             Female
24                      Female; Other
25                               Male
```